# apply function 4 times in a for loop and return 4 different objects (while the function returns 1 object at a time)

Tags: python

I have the following function that imports a keras model from local file

```py
def import_trained_keras_model(dense_layer_batch_size, version_data_control, x_train_data_shape, training_validation_split_ratio, model_loss_function, model_metric_function)
    
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'model_two\\model_glove_embeddings_{0}batchsize_{1}.json'.format(str(dense_layer_batch_size), version_data_control)),'r') as f:
        model_json = json.load(f)

    model_imported = model_from_json(model_json)

    model_imported.load_weights(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'model_two\\model_glove_embeddings_{0}batchsize_{1}.h5'.format(str(dense_layer_batch_size), version_data_control)))

    model_imported.compile(optimizer=optimizer_adam_v2(x_train_data_shape, training_validation_split_ratio, dense_layer_batch_size),
                           loss=model_loss_function neural_network_parameters['model_loss'],
                           metrics=model_metric_function [neural_network_parameters['model_metric']])
    print(type(model_imported))
    print("\nModel is loaded successfully\n")
    
    return model_imported
```

I want to apply this function 4 times and return 4 different object like below,

```py
layer_batch_size=[16, 32, 64, 128] # I have one trained model per batch size. So 4 models in total.

for i in layer_batch_size:

    model_object= import_trained_keras_model(i, "03072020", X_train_seq_features.shape[0], 0.7, "binary_crossentropy", ["accuracy"])

#and return the model_object_one (16 batch size), model_object_two (32 batch size), etc...
```

I want to use the for-loop because otherwise, I have to write 4 times the same python script. Is this feasible in Python?

To make my question clearer, I am searching for solutions more sophisticated than just saving my model_object to a list and then assign its element in the list to a different object. Only if this is feasible in Python.

I want to avoid the following (only if it's feasible):

```py
list_models=[]
layer_batch_size=[16, 32, 64, 128]

for i in layer_batch_size:
    model_object=import_trained_keras_model(i, "03072020", X_train_seq_features.shape[0], 0.7, "binary_crossentropy", ["accuracy"])
    list_models.append(model_object)
    
model_one=list_models[0]
model_two=list_models[1]
model_three=list_models[2]
model_four=list_models[3]
```

Thank you in advance for any answer or comment.

Comment: Yes just make a list `model_objects = []` before the loop, then inside the loop (after the function call) do `model_objects.append(model_object)` to add it to the list and when the loop is complete you have list `model_objects` that you can return.

Comment: @alaniwi Ok It's an option. And then apply its element in the list to a different python object like ```model_object_one = mylist[0]``` etc

Comment: @alaniwi I am into more flexible ways but if that's the best Python can do I am ok with it

Comment: There are many more possibilities - what I suggested is just a simple example - but please put your exact requirements in the question.

Comment: It's just a discussion I want to initiate. I know that there would be easy, and hard solutions. So I would like to here many different opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it would be possible to do exactly what You want by using a data structure like:

1. list
2. dictionary

Using list:

```
layer_batch_size=[16, 32, 64, 128]
result_list = []

for i in layer_batch_size:
    model_object = import_trained_keras_model(i, "03072020", X_train_seq_features.shape[0], 0.7, "binary_crossentropy", ["accuracy"])
    result_list.append(model_object)

return result_list
```

Using dictionary:

```
layer_batch_size=[16, 32, 64, 128]
result_dict = {}

for i in layer_batch_size:
    model_object = import_trained_keras_model(i, "03072020", X_train_seq_features.shape[0], 0.7, "binary_crossentropy", ["accuracy"])
    result_dict[f"{i}"] = model_object

return result_dict
```

At least that's what I suspect. I think that there are more ways to solve this particular problem but those are the ones that seem to be the easiest.

To be able to unpack the list in a named manner instead of using list index You can use:

```
m1, m2, m3, m4 = result_list #[m1, m2, m3, m4]
```

[Reference for the code above](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/) (This should work both for tuples and for lists)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although, I would prefer to avoid such a solution, even though I know it works. It would be better if you could provide a more sophisticated approach. Thank you again :)

Comment: @NikSp what do you want a "more sophisticated approach" to **do**?

Comment: check my edit on my question to see what I want to avoid

Comment: @NikSp Yes it is feasible. I will edit my response on how to unpack lists in a named manner.

Comment: I did I small change at your code and I think it's what I was looking for. Thank you a lot. :)

Comment: @NikSp Sure remember that you can always use something like this too:
`m1, m2, m3, m4 = function_returning_4_models()`